# Atmega32u4 on 5V. MISO from IC on 3.3V?

Tags: spi, atmega, 5v, 3.3v

I'm running an Atmega32u4 on a 5V circuit. However, I'm also using a Bluetooth IC [MDBT40] on a 3.3V circuit that I'm setting down from 5V with a linear regulator. I'm turning both SCK and MOSI to 3.3V using 74LVC2G34.

However, I'm a little bit stuck on the MISO line to the Atmega. From Adafruit's schematic [here](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/026/205/original/adafruit_products_BluefruitLESPIFriend_sch.png?1436186237), it seems like MISO [*despite being 3.3V*] is passed off directly. Can I connect this 3.3V signal wire to my 5V Atmega and have it function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In datasheet [ATMEGA328](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf), Page 258,

[image]

Vhigh(min) = 0.6Vcc, considering Vcc=5V, then, Vigh = 3V.

Although MISO acting as input will work on 3.3V but you would be working on the edge. If the Vcc goes low, you would not be able to read a signal.

Recommendation: Try using a level-shifter(easy to build,3.3V to 5V) or optocoupler(different voltage references) for the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! This cleared things up!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. :)